# How to add facebook like automatically in every page

Tags: php, facebook

I want to put this code in the sidebar of my website but how to code that the data-ref will automatically change when a visitor goes to another page, not the index.php

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://myinternetincome.info/index.php" data-width="250" data-height="The pixel height of the plugin" data-colorscheme="light" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-send="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put that snippet of code into its own file called `facebook_like.php` like so:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://myinternetincome.info<?php echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]; ?>" data-width="250" data-height="The pixel height of the plugin" data-colorscheme="light" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-send="true"></div>
```

***Notice the `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, this will change dependent on the page you are on.***

And then, on any pages that you would like this like widget to show, just use a simple `include` like so:

```
include('facebook_like.php');
```

Comment: @RomeoSalamida Don't forget to accept the answer if it is correct

Answer (score 0):

index.php is scriptname. You can use $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]

like this:

```
http://myinternetincome.info<?=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF];?>
```

you can edit code you want and then include this code every page.